# Deploy issues with Django / Python application on Heroku Cedar

Tags: python, django, heroku

On following the tutorial outlined here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites

I get this error:

http://pastie.org/3113885

I'm checking through a few things, but would anyone have a guess as to whats happening here?

My first guess would be its something in my local configuration, as this is the "hello world" equivalent of a django heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with pushing to the Cedar stack at the moment which I believe the engineers are looking into.

More information can be found here:  https://status.heroku.com/incident/279